# Custom color without defining new color

Tags: color

I want to do something like

```
{\color{rgb}{200,100,30}color text}
```

instead of doing

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{200,100,30}
{\color{mycolor}color text}
```

How can I achieve this? I am having difficulty understanding the xcolor pdf manual, so I am hoping someone here can help. I think it might be possible to do this using LuaLateX scripting, but I have never used LuaLaTeX and I am hoping there is an easier way.

Comment: `\color[rgb]`  not `\color{rgb}`

Comment: Thank you. And wow 6 second response time! I had a feeling this was an easy/obvious question, but for some reason I couldn't find an answer. If you want to post this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The model name (`rgb`) is mandatory when defining colors (so in `{...}`) but optional in `\color` and `\textcolor` where the default is to take a defined color name. Optional arguments are in `[...]` so

```
 {\color[RGB]{200,100,30}...}
```

Note you need RGB color model if the arguments are integers 0-255, rgb takes numbers in the range 0-1

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\textcolor[RGB]{100, 200, 100}{Colored text}
\textcolor[rgb]{1, 0.2, 0.1}{Colored text}

\end{document}
```